# How to find the states/cities of any country in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, location, country

I know that according to the method below I can get the country in woocommerce:

```
global $woocommerce;
$woocommerce->customer->get_shipping_country()
```

or

```
WC()->customer->get_shipping_country()
```

But I want to know that how to find the states/cities of any country.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In WooCommerce, you can only get states (or regions) from a country using:

```
$country_code = WC()->customer->get_shipping_country();

$states_array = WC()->countries->get_states( $country_code ); // States array for a country
```

You can get the customer shipping state with: `WC()->customer->get_shipping_state();`. 
You can get the customer shipping city with: `WC()->customer->get_shipping_city();`.